# Where to find questions from the imperial exam?

Tags: resources

I have found various pages with questions from the last imperial exam in 1904. [This](https://www.quora.com/What-types-of-questions-were-asked-on-Imperial-Examinations-during-the-Song-Dynasty) one seems most practical.

Given the immense importance of the event, I hope that more records of (prior) exams should survive. How to find them? I am also interested in any surviving answers.

Comment: Seeing the title of this question, my first thought was "someone from the qing dynasty somehow got on the internet, and they're asking for help to cheat on their homework"

Answer (score 3):

about the imperial examinaion (科舉制度), i recommend the book [釧影樓回憶錄](http://www.bnasie.eu/Asset/Source/bnBook_ID-165_No-1.pdf) by 包天笑 (page 81-103). it talked about his experience (~1890) to attend the 縣試, 府試 and 院試 (the first three entry level exams) with details; very interesting :)

the first "entry" in another book [世載堂雜憶](https://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=gb&chapter=610940) by 劉禺生, is "清代之科舉", also a good read

about questions in the exam 縣考:

> 大題者，於"四書"文中，兩章三章，或一節一句為題目，不得割裂
>
> 小題者，於"四書"文中，任擇一句為題
>
> 第一場試《論語》、《學》《庸》時文一篇，《孟子》文一篇，試帖詩一首
>
> 第二場試時文一篇，五經文一篇，試帖詩一首
>
> 第三場考八股文一篇，史論一篇，試帖一首
>
> 第四場試雜作，律賦一篇，古近體詩數首，有加時文一篇者
>
> 終場亦作時文起講，或作兩大比時文不等

about questions in 院考:

> 試題為《論語》、《學》、《庸》題目八股文一，《孟子》題目八股文一，五言六韻試帖詩一首。
>
> 翌日覆試，或作起講，或作八股文兩大比，限香一寸，並默寫正場起講

i'm sorry to provided these in chinese only, hope you can comprehend and get the info.

have fun :)